Visual Studio tabular cube: an M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source different from those defined in the model
I have a very simple tabular cube in Visual Studio.  I created parameters to represent my data source (via the Power Query Editor).  I then wrote a query to create a table.  That query uses the data source parameters.  When I try to process the table, I encounter the following error:

An M partition uses a data function which
results in access to a data source different from those defined in the
model

How can I resolve this?
For reference, my table query is:
let
    Source = Sql.Database(#"Server", #"Database"),
    #"some table" = Source{[Schema="some_schema",Item="some_table"]}[Data]
in
    #"some table"

From the following post, somebody said that a way to solve this is to declare the SQL database as a data source.  However, if I do that, my table won't be able to use the parameters.  And, when I deploy the tabular cube to the Power BI service, Power BI won't see the parameters, which isn't what I want.  I need Power BI to see the parameters so that I can set Parameter rules in a deployment pipeline.
an-m-partition-uses-a-data-function-which-results-in-access-to-a-data-source-dif

Try creating an empty query with a connection to each data source you plan to use as a parameter so the connections exist. The queries don't have to do anything but go through the connection hand shake.

I tried that.  It didn't resolve the problem.

Power BI won't let you dynamically pick the data source at runtime.  What are you actually trying to acomplish?

My goal is to be able to toggle the source (e.g., Test, Production) during development and to auto-map the desired source when I run a deployment pipeline in Power BI.  To do this in Power BI Desktop, I create a parameter for my source and reference that parameter in my M script.  That allows me to toggle during development.  And, when I run the deployment pipeline, I can set a parameter rule that defines the source when I move between Test and Production.  Is that not supported in Visual Studio?

I did a working example in my environment with 2 Analysis Server databases. Adjust this for you SQL Server environment.
You will need to create a Data Source for each database. When you create the data model in Visual Studio, you have to create Data Sources first. You can't just load a Table/Partition from a database via Source = Sql.Database(). You have to reference a Data Source such as Source = #"SqlDatabase/server", where SqlDatabase/server is the Data Source name.
(Note this is different than Power BI. In Power BI, there are no Data Source objects, only Expressions and Partitions.)
So from the Tabular Model Explorer, right click Data Sources and pick New Data Source:

Then add a Data Source for each and every database. Here are mine:

Then right click one of the Data Sources and Import New Tables:

Connect to the database and table as you normally would, and then click the Transform Data button to open Power Query.
You'll see that the Source step will reference the Data Source.

You want it to be conditional based on a Parameter, so select Query > Parameters > New Parameter:

I named mine Environment with a Type of Text, with a Suggested Values of a List of values of Test and Prod, and I set the Default and Current Values to Test:

Note that these are just text values. Go back to the Source step in the Table query and change it to use an if statement. Remember Power Query is case sensitive, and watch your use of quotes and # as shown:
let
    Source = if #"Environment" = "Test" then #"AnalysisServices/myserver_d01" else #"AnalysisServices/myserver_p01",

Now by changing the parameter, you can switch between databases.

This is exactly what I needed.  When I use this solution, I still have both data sources being moved into the Prod workspace in Power BI, but I'm now free to use a valid parameter rule, rather than a data source rule.
